# Is it possible to run Microsoft Outlook VBA when computer is in sleep?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm currently using an Outlook VBA script to save PDF attachment from an automated report email onto the company shared drive. The problem is I'm taking 2 weeks off for vacation soon, so I wonder if there's anyway I can make the VBA run when my PC is in sleep mode?

From my research I understand the VBA can't run at all if my PC is turned off, but what if I leave Outlook open and put my PC into sleep?

Below is my simple VBA script for your reference. (It is run as filtering rule)

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment

Dim saveFolder_1 As String
    saveFolder_1 = "my path 1"

Dim saveFolder_2 As String
    saveFolder_2 = "my path 2"

Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd")


For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder_1 & "\" & "file name" & dateFormat & ".pdf"
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder_2 & "\" & "file name" & dateFormat & ".pdf"
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Outlook will not run when your computer is sleeping. Normally, you can have server side rules that are executed by the Exchange server regardless of whether Outlook is connected to it, but it will not be able to run VB script or save attachments. The best you can do is move messages to other folders or to forward/delegate messages to other mailboxes.

Comment: Hi Dmitry - Thanks for explaining this to me. Guess i'll try to find some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (which is how I do it) is to run outlook on a Virtual Machine residing on an always on server. This way it doesn't matter what the state of a local machine is, Outlook will always be running and able to execute code on the server.

Comment: Virtual machine is not an option for me, but thank you all the same for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't run your code on a server, you can use the Windows Task Scheduler to wake your workstation from sleep, run the macro, and go back to sleep. Reasonably good instructions are at [this page.](http://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/)

Comment: Thanks Jay, the instruction looks very detailed. I'll give it a try.